# V8.NET (v8dotnet) mono

Tags: c#, mono, v8, embedded-v8, v8.net

Hopefully someone has a little time to explain how to use V8.Net with Mono.
I'm trying to use V8.Net with mono 3.10 on my ubuntu machine. So far I did the following:

1. create an example project with the content on codeplex

   ```
     using System;
     using V8.Net;
     namespace testv8
    {
        class MainClass
        {
                public static void Main (string[] args)
                {


                   var v8Engine = new V8Engine();
                   Handle result = v8Engine.Execute("/* Some JavaScript Code Here*/","My V8.NET Console");
                   Console.WriteLine(result.AsString); // (or "(string)result")
                   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue ...");
                   Console.ReadKey(); 


                   Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
           }
        }
     }
   ```
2. add V8.Net.dll and V8.NetSharedTypes to the references
3. I copied the content of the folder /Release/NET 4.0/x64 to /bin/Debug/x64 of my build directory
4. When I try to run the  example, I get the following error: A system.DllNotFoundException was thrown.
5. I changed the Build type from Debug to ( Debug | Any cpu ). If I [understood](https://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/documentation) correct the library should now choose the correct dll.

6 When I rerun the program in this mode.
The program stops at:
Loaded assembly: /Build/v8dotnet/testv8/testv8/bin/test/x64/V8.Net.Proxy.Interface.x64.dll [External]

The call stack shows:
V8.Net.V8NetProxy.CreatehandleProxyTest().

Hopefully you can give me some input to get it running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short note: there is some progress on making V8.Net available with Mono for different platforms (Win, Linux, and Mac).
More info is available on the following sites:
[Mono Github Branch](https://github.com/chrisber/v8dotnet/tree/development-mono)
[V8.Net Mono Issues](https://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/1273)

**Update:** Mono is no longer supported. .Net Standard is now supported instead, which is cross-platform also.

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/V8.Net/

CodePlex is now closed down. The new source is here: https://github.com/rjamesnw/v8dotnet